# Clean/Full Rebuild of a project every night in CruiseControl.NET

Tags: msbuild, build-automation, cruisecontrol.net

I've set up some rather large C++ projects to do integration builds in CruiseControl.NET, using MSBuild.

Now I'd like to schedule a complete Clean of the working directory once a night. How can I do that with CC.NET ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a project that cleans your working directory at specified time.

```
<project name="CleanWorkingDir">
<triggers>
    <scheduleTrigger time="23:30" buildCondition="ForceBuild" name="Scheduled"/>
</triggers>
<tasks>
    <exec executable="c:\projects\myproject\build.bat"/>
</tasks>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the clean copy on the source control block, everything is already done for you. All you have to do is set it to true. If you really just want a project to clean that directory, then don't have any build tasks. However, as a matter of good release engineering you really should use cleancopy with all your individual builds. Otherwise, you cnanot be sure the build would work on an absolutely clean machine.

Answer (score 0):

We created a script that deletes everything in the source directory and placed it in the prebuild step:

```
<prebuild>
    <exec>
        <executable>Clean_Source.bat</executable>
        <baseDirectory>SourceDir</baseDirectory>
    </exec>
</prebuild>
```

Comment: Won't that run every build ? I'd like a clean just once a night, as full builds take 10-12 minutes.

Comment: It will run every build.  We have two build projects that reference the same set of build parameters - an incremental build and a full build.  The full build calls this prebuild step first, then the regular incremental build is called.